# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sanitize()

Tags: php, sql, xampp

I account this error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sanitize() in
>   C:\xamppp\htdocs\webdev\admin\brands.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main}

while running the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){

 $delete_id = (int) $_GET['delete'];

  $delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);

   $sql = "DELETE FROM brand WHERE id = '$delete_id'";

    $db->query($sql);

     header('Location; brands.php');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a function as sanitise build into PHP, that's why the interpreter outputs an error.